# Uniqueness of Measures Follow-Up

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega \neq \emptyset$ and $\mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$.

Let $\mu_1, \mu_2: \mathcal{F} \to [0, \infty)$ be measures.

> **Theorem**. Let $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{F}$ be a $\pi$-system such that $\mathcal{F} = \sigma\langle \mathcal{C}\rangle$. If
>   $\mu_1(C) = \mu_2(C)$ for all $C \in \mathcal{C}$ and $\mu_1(\Omega) =
>  \mu_2(\Omega)$, then $\mu_1(A) = \mu_2(A)$ for all $A \in
>  \mathcal{F}$.

I have already shown that $\mathcal{L}:= \{A: A \in \mathcal{F}, \mu_1(A) = \mu_2(A)\}$ is a $\lambda$-system.

The book goes on to say the following:

> Since $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{L}$, by the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, $\lambda\langle\mathcal{C}\rangle = \sigma\langle\mathcal{C}\rangle$ and thus $\mathcal{L} = \sigma\langle\mathcal{C}\rangle = \mathcal{F}$.

I'm not quite following this. Is this saying that $\lambda\langle\mathcal{C}\rangle = \mathcal{L}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{L}$ is a $\lambda$-system containing $C$. By definition, $\lambda(C)$ is the smallest lambda-system containing $C$. Thus $\lambda(C)\subset\mathcal{L}$.

So $\sigma(C)\subset\mathcal{L}$, as $\lambda(C)=\sigma(C)$. We also have $\mathcal{L}\subset\mathcal{F}=\sigma(C)$. Hence $\mathcal{L}=\sigma(C)=\mathcal{F}$.